# RegEx Python not working

Tags: python, regex

My Reg-Ex pattern is not working, why?

```
string = "../../example/tobematched/nonimportant.html"
pattern = "example\/([a-z]+)\/"
test = re.match(pattern, string)
# None
```

http://www.regexr.com/39mpu

Comment: match will only match the beginning of the string. Replace match with search

Comment: Yes, `match` is perhaps the most ill-designed function in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you the answer in short:

[search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) ⇒ finds something anywhere in the string and return a match object.

[match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) ⇒ finds something at the beginning of the string and return a match object.

That is the reason you have to use

```
foo = re.search(pattern, bar)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches from the beginning of the string, you need to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) which looks for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match and returns a corresponding MatchObject instance.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "../../example/tobematched/nonimportant.html"
>>> re.search(r'example/([a-z]+)/', s).group(1)
'tobematched'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
test = re.search(pattern, string)
```

Match matches the whole string from the start, so it will give `None` as the result.

Grab the result from `test.group()`.